# Como editar a propriedade Full Path do arquivo no Visual Studio

Tags: c, c++, visual-studio

Adicionei um arquivo já existente no meu projeto.
Com isso, ele fixa o Full Path do meu arquivo, e eu não consigo mais alterar.

O que preciso fazer é editar esse valor passando a utilizar variáveis como `$(SolutionDir)`, para que o projeto compile independente do diretório em que foi baixado.

Exemplo do caso:

Fiz o include. O Full Path fica da seguinte forma: `C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\Contribs\roundto\src\roundto.c`

Quando na verdade eu precisaria que ele ficasse disponível em:
`$(SolutionDir)\..\..\src\roundto.c`

Aqui está o passo a passo que utilizo para adicionar os arquivos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou remover o arquivo e adicionar o que está dentro da estrutura do projeto?

Comment: @jbueno, se eu fizer isso, ele vai pegar o diretório atual do arquivo na minha maquina. Se alguém baixar meu projeto, vai ter que ficar ajustando conforme a maquina dele.

Comment: Ele não vai, jovem. Se você fizer o **Include in solution** ele vai incluir normal.

Comment: Sinceramente, isso nem faz muito sentido. Você tem um caso real que isso ocorra ou está supondo? A propriedade `FullPath` é a concatenação **local do projeto** com o **caminho relativo do arquivo**

Comment: @jbueno, editei a pergunta citando um exemplo

Comment: Ah, é um projeto C. Aí pode ter alguma diferença. Nos outros arquivos o `FullPath` fica dessa segunda forma?

Comment: @jbueno, ele fica sempre da primeira. O problema disso é que conforme a galera faz o pull, eles vão tendo que deletar e incluir os arquivos novamente.

Comment: Que bizarro esse comportamento. Você consegue fazer um GIF mostrando como faz pra adicionar os arquivos?

Comment: @jbueno, editado novamente, com imagens do processo

Comment: Ao invés de fazer isso, faça o seguinte: mova o arquivo (pelo filesystem mesmo) pra pasta desejada dentro da solução, depois clique no ícone "mostrar todos os arquivos" (ele fica acima da solution explorer) então vá até a pasta e você verá o arquivo esmaecido, clique nele com o botão direto e clique em "Include in project".

Comment: @jbueno, Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54170/discussion-between-victor-tadashi-and-jbueno).